# mysql or php help about text data imporing into phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql

i had text in this format

```
132B1A0101 RT22011 BUILDING PLANNING & DRAWING 16 25 3
132B1A0101 RT22012 HYDRAULICS AND HYDRAULIC MACHINERY 17 24 3
132B1A0101 RT22013 STRENGTH OF MATERIALS- II 16 30 3
132B1A0101 RT22014 MANAGERIAL ECONOMICS AND FINANCIAL ANALYSIS 22 24 3
132B1A0101 RT22015 CONCRETE TECHNOLOGY 20 37 3
132B1A0101 RT22016 STRUCTURAL ANALYSIS - I 14 18 0
132B1A0101 RT22017 FLUID MECHANICS & HYDRAULIC MACHINERY LAB 19 38 2
```

i am using this code for importing that data into mysql bur it does not help me

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/foo.txt' 
INTO TABLE foo COLUMNS TERMINATED BY '\t';
```

please help me in loading that data by mysql or php coding

Comment: not possible, since you don't have any proper separators in the text. load infile is "dumb" and you can NOT tell it that "fluid mechanis & hydraulic machiner" is a single field. you will have to write some php code to parse the lines for you and then build a proper .csv file, or just stuff the data into mysql directly.

Comment: You might need to *delimit* your data using something like `,` or a tab (four spaces).

Answer (score 0):

Try editing your `foo.txt` as so

```
132B1A0101,RT22011,"BUILDING PLANNING & DRAWING",16,25,3
132B1A0101,RT22012,"HYDRAULICS AND HYDRAULIC MACHINERY",17,24,3
132B1A0101,RT22013,"STRENGTH OF MATERIALS- II",16,30,3
132B1A0101,RT22014,"MANAGERIAL ECONOMICS AND FINANCIAL ANALYSIS",22,24,3
132B1A0101,RT22015,"CONCRETE TECHNOLOGY",20,37,3
132B1A0101,RT22016,"STRUCTURAL ANALYSIS - I",14,18,0
132B1A0101,RT22017,"FLUID MECHANICS & HYDRAULIC MACHINERY LAB",19,38,2
```

Then try the load again.

Comment: tanQ gh0st but i had a large data about 20mb like this,cannot edit that much

Comment: Maybe you can import your data into an excel spreadsheet. Then export it as a `.csv`  then run your `LOAD DATA`.

Comment: i am getting error from 3 line while i am doing that gh0st

Comment: please help me in that php coding Marc B

Comment: @LokeshReddy, are you using `"` to surround the string like I revised my post to show? Line three of the text in my answer or the text in your 20MB file?

Comment: tanQ ghost can i get any coding to get automatic " to third line